# Replace cyrillic characters in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to replace the cyrillic characters in my google spreadsheets via formulas, but can't find any variants. Can anybody help me to write some script in google docs scripts or macros which replaces any Russian symbols in the column and as a result I want to get only latin symbols. As an example, I have "Абажур Glamour 14x13 см, серебристый" in one row, "Balloon Smoke напольная лампа 53x135 см серебристо-дымчатого оттенка", where I want to have "Glamour" and "Balloon Smoke" as a result.

Comment: If you need this to be scripted, then please include your own attempt for reference. If formulas are fine then try to utilize `REGEXEXTRACT` or `REGEXREPLACE`. For example use: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?i)\b[A-Z]+\b(?:\s[A-Z]+\b)*")`.

Comment: Here is my sheets
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RI9ehwPLLA3fkZVGhfg6H8drGX_XuAm1fxo10aqZeME/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's working! Thank you, my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As mentioned by [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv), [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) can be used to extract the Latin characters:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2;"(?i)\b[A-Z]+\b(?:\s[A-Z]+\b)*")
```

#### Reference:

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)